# It's okay if I do not write add_action()

Tags: themes, functions, hooks

I downloaded various themes on net and I found on `functions.php` they write something like this

Example to remove inline comment style.

```
function demo_remove_recent_comments_style() {
    add_filter( 'show_recent_comments_widget_style', '__return_false' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'demo_remove_recent_comments_style' );
```

Question

Why we not write only this without a `function()`

```
add_filter( 'show_recent_comments_widget_style', '__return_false' );
```

Let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not always *required* technically but it is *good practice* to follow for multiple reasons:

1. Code is more organized by keeping hook-related stuff together
2. The more precise conditions when it runs - the better for performance
3. It is easier to unhook function, that performs multiple *add*_, then unhook each *add*_ individually.
4. The order of adding functions matters when not specifying priority.
5. The child theme (if used) is processed before parent theme and it can lead to confusing stuff with hooks if *add*_ and *remove*_ are performed inline.

Of course in some specific examples (yours does fit) it does seem overly verbose to write out all of that just to manipulate single item on single hook.

Myself I use couple of my own (and somewhat messy functions) - `add_filter_return()` and `add_action_with_arguments()` to lower amount of wrapping when working with hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, it's difficult to know exactly why, but generally, this might offer a marginal improvement to site performance.

As written, the `add_action` function limits how often the `add_filter` function is fired. It will only execute when the `widgets_init` hook is encountered before the `show_recent_comments_widget_style` hook. On the same note, the `show_recent_comments_widget_style` hook can be used in the code without executing the add_filter function.

Without the `function()`, the code would fire each time the `show_recent_comments_widget_style` hook was encountered, whether or not the `widgets_init` function came first.

Comment: It's will hurt our speed performance?

Comment: Regardless of which way it is coded, I would imagine that you will not notice an impact on performance. However, throughout your theme, the stricter the conditions, the better your site will perform.